# Converting postgresql indexes to Django migrations

Tags: django, postgresql

We have a Django application that has been in production since Django 1.1. Over the years, we've manually added bells and whistles to the production PostgreSQL db that weren't at the time overtly supported by Django's db automation, especially in the form of custom indexes.

Django's come a long way since 1.1, and now w/ 1.10 I'm pretty sure the migration framework supports all the custom features we've added manually. Is there any automated tool which will compare a database to the models, and generate migrations to bring the models up to date with the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is built into django, you can just run [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb)

```
manage.py inspectdb
```

> Introspects the database tables in the database pointed-to by the NAME setting and outputs a Django model module (a models.py file) to standard output. You may choose what tables to inspect by passing their names as arguments.
>
> Use this if you have a legacy database with which you’d like to use Django. The script will inspect the database and create a model for each table within it.

Comment: Ha, "batteries included", indeed. I'd read about that feature before, but had completely forgotten about it. Thanks!